# Authorize.net: How to validate the credit card using "AUTH_ONLY"?

Tags: php, authorize.net

I am using the authorize.net AIM Module transaction. Now I want to validate the CreditCard Number , Expiry Date and CCV Number with out charging the credit card.

I used **AUTH_ONLY** method in x_type and passed amount as "0.00". It didnt worked. SO I changed the amount to "0.01". It worked. As per my assumption "0.01" charged from the card and saw the transaction in the report, Without charging I need to validate the card. As per their documentation It will not charge. Buts its charging.

Can any one help me on this ? Also please explain the difference between **AUTH_ONLY** and **AUTH_CAPTURE**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AUTH_ONLY transactions are only kept in your Unsettled Transactions for 30 days. If an AUTH_ONLY transaction is not captured for settlement within 30 days, the transaction status will change to Expired, and the funds will not be transferred.

http://support.authorize.net/authkb/index?page=content&id=A510&pmv=print&impressions=false Full list of transactions can be found here.

There is one more option to validate credit card
AUTH_CAPTURE + VOID combination, that will charge and refund transaction.

Comment: But the Transactions "0.01" will be listed in the Customers statement right ?

Comment: I think , customers don't see the authorization as a charge on their statement, but they will see that available funds were decreased by the amount you ran the authorization for.